# unable to use create_job function using s3 control for batch operations

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, operation

I am unable to understand how to fill in the fields inside the create_job function. (specifically manifest parameter). I would really appreciate if someone would give a real time example for the create_job function as i could not find it on the internet. 
What i need to do is to add tags to multiple objects at once.
code which i have written and understood till now is below:

```
client = boto3.client('s3control')
response = client.create_job(
AccountId='682283364620 ',
Operation={

    'S3PutObjectTagging': {
        'TagSet': [
            {
                'Key': 'naturalnumber',
                'Value': 'yo'
            },
        ]
    }
},
Report={
    'Bucket': 'shivam1052061',
    'Format': 'Report_CSV_20180820',
    'Enabled': True,
    'Prefix': 'string',
    'ReportScope': 'AllTasks'
},
ClientRequestToken='',
Manifest={
    'Spec': {
        'Format': 'S3BatchOperations_CSV_20180820',
        'Fields': [
            'Ignore'|'Bucket'|'Key'|'VersionId',
        ]
    },
    'Location': {
        'ObjectArn': 'string',
        'ObjectVersionId': 'string',
        'ETag': 'string'
    }
},
Description='string',
Priority=123,
RoleArn='string'
```

)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the manifest files that S3 Inventory with the Object ARN an ETag

```
Manifest={
   'Spec': { 
       'Format': 'S3InventoryReport_CSV_20161130'
   },
   'Location': {
       'ObjectArn': 'arn:aws:s3:::bucket/report/2020-08-17T00-00Z/manifest.json',
       'ETag': 'xxxxxxxxx'
   }
}
```